Extract one particular file from a .deb package file
If I manually download a .deb file (for example, with apt install --download-only which saves the file to /var/cache/apt/archives/), how can I list the files it contains and extract one particular file?

Does this answer your question? Can I download a file from a package without installing it?

To list the files in the package:
dpkg --contents foobar.deb

To extract a particular file:
dpkg --fsys-tarfile foobar.deb | tar -xO ./path/to/file.ext > file.ext

Thanks to https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2003/04/msg02861.html for the tip.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Another option is to open the .deb file in File Roller, which works just as well for Debian packages as it does for zip files and tarballs.

File Roller from Flatpak might not be able to do this, at least in the older version I have on an Ubuntu 20.04-based distro (elementaryOS). Instead, I receive an error There is no command installed for Debian package files. Do you want to search for a command to open this file? followed by There was an internal error trying to search for applications: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown. If this happens to you, try one of the terminal-based options mentioned above.

You can list package files using:
  dpkg -c /var/cache/apt/archives/foo_1.2.3.deb

Then extract whole package into a foo_1.2.3
  dpkg-deb -x /var/cache/apt/archives/foo_1.2.3.deb foo_1.2.3

if you're interested in package scripts (preinst, postinst, ...)
  dpkg-deb -e /var/cache/apt/archives/foo_1.2.3.deb foo_1.2.3-scripts


looks like "dpkg-query -L" lists files only for installed package. Instead there is "dpkg -c / --contents xxx.deb" for standalone deb file

@pmod Yeah, you're right, thanks.
